# Pandas df to json - request using

Tags: json, pandas, request

I need to use request package to use API. The API from IT takes a JSON string which look exactly like this:

```
{
  "StoreCode": "7144",
  "GlovoStoreCode": "7144_1",
  "ProductList": [
    {
      "GlovoId": "10"
    },
    {
      "GlovoId": "10"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a DF frame (image) and I am using `.to_json` function but I cant get result like should be.
Could please someone let me knot how to convert my df to result exactly like API needs. Really thanks!

```
StoreCode   GlovoStoreCode  ProductList
```

0   4452    4452_1  360908
1   4452    4452_1  125539
2   4452    4452_1  297758
3   4452    4452_1  2025651

[image: DF AND MY REQUEST RESULT]

Comment: Seems like you are not getting a successful response (2xx) from the web service. Try printing `r.status_code`.

Comment: Sorry. I understand now. This really depends on the implementation on the server side.

But `requests.post` for python has a parameter `json` where you can send the data itself without having to use `json.dumps`. 

Refer to link:
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert the types to match the request.

```
df["StoreCode"]=df["StoreCode"].astype(str)
df["GlovoStoreCode"]=df["GlovoStoreCode"].astype(str)
```

Only performing the transformation for 1st item. Setup a loop if you want to do it for multiple rows.

```
first_item=df.to_dict(orient="records")[0]
first_item["ProductList"]=[{"GlovoID":i} for i in first_item["GlovoID"]]
del first_item["GlovoID"]
first_item=json.dumps(first_item)
```